# ASP.NET MVC ListBoxFor Multiselect control (The value '1,2' is invalid.)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple MVC application with a multi select list that currently throws the following error on submission: The value '1,2' is invalid.

**Model**

```
public class FormData
{
    public int FormDataId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one Type of Health Insurer")]
    [DisplayName("Type of Health Insurer")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> InsurerTypes { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
List<SelectListItem> typeItemList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        typeItemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Type A" });
        typeItemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Type B" });
        typeItemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Type C" });
        typeItemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Type D" });
        typeItemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "Type E" });

        ViewBag.TypeItemList = typeItemList;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.FormDatas.Add(formData);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(formData);
```

**View**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InsurerTypes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "required control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.InsurerTypes, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.TypeItemList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", Multiple = "multiple" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsurerTypes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have looked at the following articles for help but have had no luck:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/265/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlists-multiple-selection-and-enum-support

http://www.mitechdev.com/2016/04/multi-select-dropdown-in-mvc5.html

**Edit - Updated Model:**

```
public class FormData
{
    public int FormDataId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> InsurerTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedInsurers { get; set; }
}
```

The model now appears to be working as I can see the list of selected items on  db.FormDatas.Add(formData).  However it does not appear to be saving to the database as that column is just null.

Comment: You using a listbox which is for selecting multiple values - your property needs to be `public IEnumerable<int> FormDataId { get; set; }` and the view `@@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.FormDataId, Model.InsurerTypes, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Also the `[Required]` and `[Display]` (not `[DisplayName]`) attributes need to be on the property your binding to, not the `SelectList`.

Comment: That's assuming you want the selected option values to be bound to property `FormDataId` - otherwise you need another property (say) `public IEnumerable<int> SelectedInsurers { get; set; }` to bind to.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, that got me a bit further along.  Now the issue I am dealing with is the values not saving to the database.  I have updated the model above.  What SQL type should I be using to house the list values, neither nvarchar or int has worked so far.

Comment: You cant have a column in a database with is `IEnumerable`. You need a second table for storing the selected values with a FK to first table.